# How to parse a YAML file with value present in multiple lines

Tags: linux, shell

I have a YAML file in the below format with some values spanned to multiple lines.

```
key1: value1
key2: description\
    \ description followed in next line \n
    \ Another line of string
```

I am using grep command "grep '^key1'" and "grep '^key2'" to capture values for the keys but for multiple line values only the 1st line is captured. Is there any way we can capture multiple line values from the YAML file.

Thanks

Comment: Use [`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) or another YAML-aware tool, not `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

As Shawn suggested, you should consider using a yaml parser like `yq`.  Python has a YAML parsing module.  If you are desperate, you can try this code:

```
$ FILE=sandeep.yaml  ; KEY=key2 ; VALUE=$( python3 -c "from  yaml import load; f = open('$FILE'); y = load(f) ; print( y['$KEY'] )")

$ echo $VALUE
description\ \ description followed in next line \n \ Another line of string
```

The above code requires the yaml module to be present on your system.  You may need to invoke this command in order to get the code above to work:

```
pip3 install PyYaml
```